# Disable a 'enter/return' key function in a form

Tags: 7, javascript, navigation

I have a form in which a user needs to fill the fields. As only two fields are the required fields, so when user fills the required fields and press `enter`(windows)/`return`(mac) key the form gets submitted. I'm trying to disable the `enter/return` key function. So, for this I tried to inject a `jQuery` within the form.

my jQuery is as follows:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.YOURTHEMENAME = {
attach: function(context, settings) {
$("input").keypress(function (evt) {
var enterCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
if (enterCode  == 13) { return false;
}
});
  }
});
}
};
})(jQuery);
```

The jQuery part is familiar to me, but it doesn't work in the site. And the form responds to enter/return key press.

Is there any other way to disable enter/return key press. something like a module..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue. Added the Query using `JS injector`.

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.YOURTHEMENAME = {
attach: function(context, settings) {
$('#id').keypress(function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == '13') {
       event.preventDefault();
   }
});
}
};
})(jQuery);
```

return/enter key press is now disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use evt.preventDefault();

I [wrote a blog post](http://cscrunch.com/blog/corey-pennycuff/make-html-form-navigation-behave-spreadsheet) on making this work with drupal and ajaxified forms, which may let you see a slightly larger example including Drupal.behaviors.

Comment: In "input.some-identifier", what is some-identifier here?? is that any identifier name of a div, that we are supposed to call that action??

Comment: The example on my blog is written to loop through many elements to make them behave in a spreadsheet-type fashion, so "input.some-identifier" is how the multiple form elements were identified.  In other words, it is a JQuery selector.

Comment: so, I followed the guidelines. cleared cache, but there was no effect. form responds as submit when enter key pressed

Comment: can you show the code that you are using now?

Comment: I'm using the same code that was mentioned in the blog post except the for loop.

Comment: have you verified that the code is executing, perhaps by adding console debugging or an alert box inside the keypress function?

Comment: ya, i used an alert. the code is not executing.

Comment: how are you adding the javascript?  and did you clear the caches?

Comment: I'm using javascript injector to add javascript. I cleared the cache.

Comment: You might not be able to add to Drupal.behaviors from a javascript injector.  The problem is that either your javascript might overwrite someone else's behavior, or theirs might be overwriting yours.  I suggest that you make a small custom module, put your js into a file, and include the file using [your module's .info file](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202#scripts).

Comment: Now, I wrote a js file. I added the file in my theme directory i.e., sites/all/themes/mytheme/ added the .js file. And in the mytheme.info file i added the code script[] = /js/file.js. cleared the cache. Doesn't work

Comment: You definitely shouldn't put a slash at the beginning of the "js/file.js".  Try removing, clear cache again, and see what happens.  Are any errors showing up in your console?

Comment: removed the slash. no change, it doesn't even show the alert

Comment: At this point, it's probably something very fundamental wrong that is causing the page not to load.  Is the name of your theme exactly the same as you are putting in for YOURTHEMENAME?  Is the script included in the html head section?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15599/discussion-between-giri-and-coreyp-1).

Comment: where is 'YOURTHEMENAME' in the script? I only find Drupal.behaviors.YOUR_MODULE_NAME in the script.

Comment: Do you mean YOUR_MODULE_NAME??

Comment: sadly, it's not letting me chat yet, even though I have more points than are necessary.  As for YOURTHEMENAME, I took that from your code that you posted in the initial question.  I agree that I'm not sure if behaviors works with themes, which is why I suggested making a small custom module earlier.